# How to embed a UITableView in a custom view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-component

## Goal

I want to create a custom view that has a UITableView as a subview.

[image]

The custom view creates the table view programmatically. To the outside world (i.e., the ViewController), though, the custom view itself would appear to be a table view.

## What I've tried

```
import UIKit
class CustomTableView: UIView {
    
    // Do I make outlets?
    //@IBOutlet var dataSource: UITableViewDataSource?
    //@IBOutlet var delegate: UITableViewDelegate?
    
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        var tableView: UITableView!
        tableView = UITableView(frame: self.bounds)
        // I'm not sure how to set the delegate and dataSource
        // tableView.dataSource = ???
        // tableView.delegate = ???
        
        self.addSubview(tableView)
       
    }
}
```

After creating the UITableView programmatically and adding it as a subview to the custom view parent, I can't figure out how to get the custom view to act like it is the table view. That is, I don't know how to get the custom view to do the communication between the View Controller and the table view for the `delegate` and `dataSource`.

## What I've read

- [Designing Your Data Source and Delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCellsandViews/CreatingCellsandViews.html)
- [Create a static UITableView without Storyboards](http://derpturkey.com/create-a-static-uitableview-without-storyboards/)

These articles seemed good, but I got a little lost.

How do I make the custom view act like it's own table subview with regard to delegate and data source?

Comment: Normally the only way a UIView would "appear" to be s table view to a view controller is if it in fact is s subclass of UITableView. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @algal, in this case I don't mean to subclass UITableView. I'm trying to make a horizontal TableView for vertical Mongolian. The only way I could get auto layout to work when I was doing this for a vertical Mongolian TextView was to wrap it in two container views. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30952595/3681880) and its question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is to make the `tableView` a property of the custom class (as @BaseZen suggested). Then provide properties and methods in the custom class to mimic and pass along the properties and methods needed from `tableView`.

```
import UIKit
@IBDesignable class UICustomTableView: UIView {

    private var myTableView: UITableView

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        myTableView = UITableView()
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect){
        myTableView = UITableView()
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    // TODO: @IBOutlet still can't be set in IB
    @IBOutlet weak var delegate: UITableViewDelegate? {
        get {
            return myTableView.delegate
        }
        set {
            myTableView.delegate = newValue
        }
    }

    // TODO: @IBOutlet still can't be set in IB
    @IBOutlet weak var dataSource: UITableViewDataSource? {
        get {
            return myTableView.dataSource
        }
        set {
            myTableView.dataSource = newValue
        }
    }

    func registerClass(cellClass: AnyClass?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String) {
        myTableView.registerClass(cellClass, forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
    }

    func dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier: String) -> UITableViewCell? {
        return myTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // ...

        // setup UITableView
        myTableView.frame = self.bounds
        self.addSubview(myTableView)

        // ...
    }       
}
```

Then it can be used like a normal `UITableView`:

```
import UIKit
class TableViewDemoVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var customTableView: UICustomTableView!

    var items: [String] = ["One", "Two", "Three"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // setup the table view from the IB reference
        customTableView.delegate = self
        customTableView.dataSource = self
        customTableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell: UITableViewCell = self.customTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell!
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]            
        return cell
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not the most elegant, but jump out a level:

```
class MyCustomViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        myCustomView = CustomTableView()
        myCustomView.frame = ... /* layout programatically */
        /* Alternatively to the above 2 lines, 
           lay out myCustomView in StoryBoard,
           and capture it as an @IBOutlet. It will then be ready here
           to muck with, well before it gets displayed and needs the data */
        myCustomView.tableView.delegate = self
        myCustomView.tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    /* Now implement all your dataSource and delegate methods */
}
```

*** IMPORTANT ***

The key that you're missing is that `tableView` must be a stored property of your custom view. It's important and needs to be promoted from a silly local! It should also be initialized in the awakeFromNib() function, even if you don't know the frame size. Then reset its frame at layout time.

At a higher level, I don't know "What You're Really Trying To Do." It may not actually be the right implementation technique to be embedding a UITableView within a custom view; consider just laying out the UITableView in the main view. Then if you need decoration around it, lay those out as separate views in StoryBoard.

Comment: Thank you. I will play around with making `tableView` a property. Ideally I would like to take out the middle layer in `myCustomView.tableView.delegate` and just do `myCustomView.delegate`. What I am really trying to do is make a horizontally scrolling table view for use with traditional Mongolian. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28544714/how-do-you-make-a-vertical-text-uilabel-and-uitextview-for-ios-in-swift) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30907710/rotating-a-view-in-layoutsubviews) question. I'm trying to make it behave just like a regular UITableView.

Comment: In that case subclass UITableView and put your custom code there, rather than wrapping it with a trivial layer that adds nothing. Be sure to update the class setting to your custom subclass in StoryBoard's Identity Inspector. I might ask why get hung up on `TableView`? Rotating it 90 degrees is easy but causes oddities like callout indicators appear at the top or bottom which feels wrong. Instead why not use `UICollectionView`? It's more work up front but you just use a flow layout and get lots of layout flexibility.

Comment: I'll look into `UICollectionView`. The reason I can't just rotate (and flip) a subclassed `TableView` is that auto layout no longer works on a view that has been transformed. [Using two container views](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30952595/3681880) is a workaround for that, albeit less than ideal.