# Not able to create custom view

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I wanted to create a custom view. So I designed my view like so..it's called `TagResolutionView.xib`

[This is how I designed my view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvD6K.png)

And the `TagResolutionView.swift` file for that looks like this

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class TagResolutionView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var tagResolutionView: UIView!

    @IBOutlet var tableview: UITableView!

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        tableview = UITableView()

    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
          tableview = UITableView()
        super.init(frame: frame)
      }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

       @IBOutlet weak var delegate: UITableViewDelegate? {
           get {
               return tableview.delegate
           }
           set {
               tableview.delegate = newValue
           }
       }

       @IBOutlet weak var dataSource: UITableViewDataSource? {
           get {
               return tableview.dataSource
           }
           set {
               tableview.dataSource = newValue
           }
       }

    func registerClass(cellClass: AnyClass?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String) {
        tableview.register(cellClass, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellClass")
    }

    func dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier: String) -> UITableViewCell? {
        return tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier)
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        tableview.frame = self.bounds
        self.addSubview(tableview)
    }

}
```

This is how I inserted the view in my main viewcontroller where I want the custom view to appear..

[This is the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVzUO.png)

This is how I configured it in the viewcontroller..

In the `viewDidLoad`..

```
    stdProcedViewHeight.constant = 533 //Since the view I took above (as given in the pic) is less than the height of the actual TagResolutionView.xib, I increased its height here programatically.
    standardsProceduresView.delegate = self
    standardsProceduresView.dataSource = self



standardsProceduresView.registerClass(cellClass: UpdatingListTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellClass") //I have also made .xib & .swift files for UpdatingListTableViewCell
```

Also added these methods..

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: UpdatingListTableViewCell = self.standardsProceduresView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier: "cellClass") as! UpdatingListTableViewCell
  //  cell.nameLbl.text = "MyName"
    return cell

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}
```

But I'm not able to get the desired output by doing all of this...All I get is just an empty tableview of the set height(height of 533 here) and nothing else of the design...

Comment: you are using static cells for your tableView ?

Comment: No @jawadAli.. I designed a separate custom tableview cell..

Comment: why you are reinitiating tableview ?

Comment: you dont need to do this `tableview = UITableView()`

Comment: Oh..ok @jawadAli..Actually I had referred this post in writing the code above...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688938/how-to-embed-a-uitableview-in-a-custom-view

Comment: Would you mind maybe suggesting how I might do it..?

Comment: you are mixing things ... the link you gave does not have ... `iboutlet` of tableView

Comment: I think I might have lost things somewhere..:(

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your table view doesn't show up is that you're resetting all of its content by calling `tableView = UITableView()` in your code.

It seems like you're using Storyboards, so assuming you properly connected your UITableView to the property outlet `@IBOutlet var tableview: UITableView!`, your table view will appear just fine and you don't need to initialize it via code.

I can also see that you're setting the frame of your table view and adding it to the view hierarchy in the `layoutSubviews()` method. That's definitely not something you need/want to do, first because you're using Storyboards and it means that your table view will already be part of the view hierarchy at this point.

I'd also mention that you should generally never add a subview in the `layoutSubviews()` method, because this method may be called multiple times and it means your view would be added multiple times to the view hierarchy, which would end up wasting memory.

Comment: Ok @Alex Linares...so I'll remove `tableView = UITableView()` and also the `layoutSubviews()` function..?

Comment: dont remove it, instead of `tableView = UITableView()` create an outlet of tableView like that, `@IBOutlet private weak var tableView: UITableView!`. also make sure all your outlets are to the fileowner.

Comment: But @AvivFrenkel..I have already made an outlet for tableview like so..`@IBOutlet var tableview: UITableView!`

Comment: I tried what you suggested @AvivFrenkel..But I'm getting a crash here...`tableview.delegate = newValue`

Comment: Now I'm able to see my custom view properly..But the tableview is empty..It's not showing any cells..