# Slow load time for custom UIView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, performance, xcode-instruments, mongolian-vertical-script

**Background**

In order to make a text view that scrolls horizontally for [vertical Mongolian script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28544714/how-do-you-make-a-vertical-text-uilabel-and-uitextview-for-ios-in-swift), I made a custom `UIView` subclass. The class takes a `UITextView`, puts it in a `UIView`, rotates and flips that view, and then puts that view in a parent `UIView`.

[image]

The purpose for the rotation and flipping is so that the text will be vertical and so that line wrapping will work right. The purpose of sticking everything in a parent `UIView` is so that Auto layout will work in a storyboard. (See more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30907710/rotating-a-view-in-layoutsubviews).)

**Code**

I got a working solution. The full code on github is [here](https://github.com/suragch/MongolAppDevelopment-iOS/blob/master/Mongol%20App%20Componants/UIMongolTextView.swift), but I created a new project and stripped out all the unnecessary code that I could in order to isolate the problem. The following code still performs the basic function described above but also still has the slow loading problem described below.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class UIMongolTextView: UIView {

    private var view = UITextView()
    private var oldWidth: CGFloat = 0
    private var oldHeight: CGFloat = 0

    @IBInspectable var text: String {
        get {
            return view.text
        }
        set {
            view.text = newValue
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    override func sizeThatFits(size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        // swap the length and width coming in and going out
        let fitSize = view.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: size.height, height: size.width))
        return CGSize(width: fitSize.height, height: fitSize.width)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // layoutSubviews gets called multiple times, only need it once
        if self.frame.height == oldHeight && self.frame.width == oldWidth {
            return
        } else {
            oldWidth = self.frame.width
            oldHeight = self.frame.height
        }

        // Remove the old rotation view
        if self.subviews.count > 0 {
            self.subviews[0].removeFromSuperview()
        }

        // setup rotationView container
        let rotationView = UIView()
        rotationView.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: CGSize(width: self.bounds.height, height: self.bounds.width))
        rotationView.userInteractionEnabled = true
        self.addSubview(rotationView)

        // transform rotationView (so that it covers the same frame as self)
        rotationView.transform = translateRotateFlip()

        // add view
        view.frame = rotationView.bounds
        rotationView.addSubview(view)

    }

    func translateRotateFlip() -> CGAffineTransform {

        var transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity

        // translate to new center
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, (self.bounds.width / 2)-(self.bounds.height / 2), (self.bounds.height / 2)-(self.bounds.width / 2))
        // rotate counterclockwise around center
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, CGFloat(-M_PI_2))
        // flip vertically
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1)

        return transform
    }

}
```

**Problem**

I noticed that the custom view loads very slowly. I'm new to Xcode Instruments so I watched the helpful videos [Debugging Memory Issues with Xcode and Profiler](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQmflj8jOvg) and [Time Profiler](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R2L_RwaXG78).

After that I tried finding the issue in my own project. It seems like no matter whether I use the Time Profiler or Leaks or Allocations tools, they all show that my class `init` method is doing too much work. (But I kind of knew that already from the slow load time before.) Here is a screen shot from the Allocations tool:

[image]

I didn't expand all of the call tree because it wouldn't have fit. Why are so many object being created? When I made a three layer custom view I knew that it wasn't ideal, but the number of layers that appears to be happening from the call tree is ridiculous. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have a same situation.I would expect to resolve the above problem.

Comment: My slow point is 'super.init(coder: aDecoder)' in 'required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) '.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't add or delete any subview inside `layoutSubviews`, as doing so triggers a call to `layoutSubviews` again.

Create your subview when you create your view, and then only adjust its position in `layoutSubviews` rather than deleting and re-adding it.

Comment: I have broken this rule in a pinch along with code that makes sure that it is only added once.

Comment: Trying to follow your advice, I cut out all of the code in the `layoutSubviews` method, but I was still getting a similar delay. I started a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199956/slow-load-time-for-custom-uiview-with-uitextview-property-in-swift) for it. Please let me know if you have any thoughts.