# Why Create An UITextView For The First Time On iPad Very Slowly

Tags: ios, swift, ipad

```
let textView = UITextView()
```

When the apps run and create an UITextView for the first time, it took about 2 seconds on simulator,same problem on device.But it does not has this problem after that, it only happen when the apps first run.
Why and how to fix it?

Comment: How have you determined that that particular line is taking two seconds?

Comment: By breakpoint,not exactly 2 seconds,but cost much time to pass this line.

Comment: Might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199956/slow-load-time-for-custom-uiview-with-uitextview-property-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

Is the view that contain textView is the first screen?

If yes, is it possible that you have an empty launch screen that make you thought it was slow?