# Flutter: Vertical Text widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I looked up here and pub.dev and flutter docs but could not find(or could not word my query) any solution for this simple task.

I want to display a `String` with its letters going from up to down while keeping the letter orientations default. So a rotated `Text()` would not work.

My desired outcome is this:

```
H
E
L   T
L   H
O   A
    N
W   K
O   S
R   ❤️
L
D
```

Also, I would need to wrap the `String` to the next line(column in this case) A height parameter is necessary to limit the number of letters from top to down for each column.

If this last part is too hard to implement, I am open to ideas for the single column solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

**Code:**

```
// Create a custom widget like this
class MyVerticalText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;

  const MyVerticalText(this.text);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Wrap(
      runSpacing: 30,
      direction: Axis.vertical,
      alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
      children: text.split("").map((string) => Text(string, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22))).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

And use it like:

```
MyVerticalText("HELLO WORLD THANKS❤️")
```

Comment: Wow! looks great and with such little code. I will try it asap. One quick question before trying the code: Do you think every letter becoming a `Text` widget would cause any performance issues?

Comment: It depends on the length of your string, if you are passing 10-20 letters then `Wrap` is OK but if you have say 100+ letters I would suggest you to use `ListView` instead of `Wrap` but that may not suit your UI since it will have scrolling effect, it all depends on your use case.

Comment: Actually I will be using these Vertical texts inside of a `ListView` element. So each `ListView` item has at most 2 words. And at one time we have at most 10 items on the screen.

Comment: That shouldn't be any problem then. You are good to go but one performance tip, instead of using that method, convert it to a `StatelessWidget` class. If you don't know how to convert, let me know I'll update the post.