# Flutter: How to cover the whole Column with only one of its children

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a column with multiple children which are `Flexible` widgets with different `flex` values. (My actual implementation is more complex with nested rows/columns but finding a solution to this simple case would help)

When I change the `Flex` values programmatically, the children adapt nicely to their parent WITH a nice **animation** which comes out of the box. I can make them taller/shorter with ease.

However, when I want one of the children to cover all of the `Column` all by itself and set `flex=0` for other children, it does not work. In the documentation it says setting `flex` to `0` or `null` means that the `Flexible` widget is no more "flexible"

How would I go about with this? Any idea is welcome.

[image: Current setup]

As you can see from the image: I want to set the flex value of the Green area from 3 to 0 and only be able to see Blue area covering the whole screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

You can however use `Flexible` instead of `Expanded` for 2nd child, that will work too.

**Code:**

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  int flex1 = 1, flex2 = 0;

  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          flex: flex1,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            height: 100,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text("Flex: $flex1", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded( // you can use Flexible also 
          flex: flex2,
          child: flex2 == 0 ? SizedBox() : Container(
            color: Colors.green,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text("Flex: $flex2", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi and thanks, I tried your solution and however it works as to hide the second child, it does the changes instantly without any grow/shrink animation. How would I manage this too? I read somewhere about AnimatedContainer. would it do the effect?

Comment: That should be a different standalone question.

Comment: I can write a question if you have the answer of course however in my question in bold letters I told about the Animation part specifically.

Comment: Definitely you mentioned that but you also mentioned `children adapt nicely to their parent WITH a nice animation which comes out of the box.`, but that's not true, is it?

Comment: And to be honest, I'll not be able to answer your question today cause I am leaving in next few mins. I can answer it tomorrow for sure, once I get time.

Comment: I guess you are right about the "out of the box" part. So would you want me to change the question or write a new one?

Comment: I am sure it would take you a few minutes 

Comment: If there is an easier way to have the final effect happen, I am open to ideas without Expanded/Flexible too. I just want a nicely growing/shrinking Containers which are inside Row/Column with animation

Comment: I wish it could take just couple of mins, but I don't think that would be the case here. It is a good question to ask. Without `Expanded/Flexible` it is very easy to do and won't only take few mins

Comment: Sure please post the question with detail, tag me and I'll answer it (but I think with Expanded/Flexible  it isn't going to be an easy job), but as you said you are open to other ideas, I can get that way

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58328393/flutter-how-to-expand-a-child-to-cover-the-area-of-the-parent-column-while-rest

Comment: I posted the question and if you think it needs more details, images, I can do it. Since you are doing the brain work here, I can do the paper works:D

Comment: Haha, no worries, your question is good, I just upvoted it. I am short of time today as I mentioned before, so can't promise it to answer today. But surely by tomorrow.

Comment: Do you have any idea of this? seems nobody implemented something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58310795/flutter-vertical-directional-words-with-default-letter-orientation

Comment: It is pretty much doable, all you need is use `Wrap` in `Transform` widget and split your string by '' to convert it to a `List` and assign it to `children`, right now I am busy on  some project and can answer it later on.