# Flutter: How to use AnimatedContainer with Expanded in Column?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Let's say we have 3 children of a `Column`:

```
Flexible(
   flex:1,
   child: Container(
      color: Colors.red,
   ),
),
Flexible(
   flex:3,
   child: Container(
      color: Colors.yellow,
   ),
),
Flexible(
   flex:1,
   child: Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
   ),
),
```

I want to programmatically expand middle child with `flex=3` to cover the whole `Column` with smooth animation, while the top and bottom children shrinks accordingly.

Right now my setup is with a `Column` and `Flexible` widgets. However if you can think of a solution with other widgets, I am open to those ideas as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Animate Collapsing Elements in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49029841/how-to-animate-collapsing-elements-in-flutter)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

**Code:**

```
Duration _duration = Duration(seconds: 1);
int _flex1 = 1, _flex2 = 3, _flex3 = 1;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
  var height1 = (_flex1 * height) / (_flex1 + _flex2 + _flex3);
  var height2 = (_flex2 * height) / (_flex1 + _flex2 + _flex3);
  var height3 = (_flex3 * height) / (_flex1 + _flex2 + _flex3);

  return Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        AnimatedContainer(
          duration: _duration,
          color: Colors.blue,
          height: height1,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text("Flex: ${_flex1}", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        ),
        AnimatedContainer(
          duration: _duration,
          color: Colors.red,
          height: height2,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text("Flex: ${_flex2}", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        ),
        AnimatedContainer(
          duration: _duration,
          color: Colors.teal,
          height: height3,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text("Flex: ${_flex3}", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: how can i get `fullscreen` on middle flex?

Comment: Very elegant solution. You couldn't wait until tomorrow right? :) thanks have a good night. I will be tagging you another question soon:D take care

Comment: @DolDurma You can get full screen effect by setting `flex1 = 0`, `flex2 = 1` and `flex3 = 0`.

Comment: @aytunch Haha, I wanted to wait if you had specifically mentioned to get it solved using either `Expanded` or `Flexible` but as you said you were open to other ideas, it only took less than 5 mins to solve it. Glad to hear it worked the way you wanted it. Let me know if you have any questions, always happy to help!

Comment: I'm stuck with `Expanded` and `Flexible` because I have no way to determine the maximum height of my parent widget. Is there any solution that really uses widgets with `flex` parameter?

Comment: @Jérémy You can use `LayoutBuilder` to get the maximum height.

Answer (score 2):

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58328486/6618622) is good for full screen (without `AppBar`), so if you are going to use a standard `AppBar` use this solution instead.

```
Duration _duration = Duration(seconds: 1);
int _flex1 = 1, _flex2 = 1, _flex3 = 1;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  var data = MediaQuery.of(context);

  // subtracted status bar and AppBar height from total height
  double height = data.size.height - data.padding.top - kToolbarHeight;
  var height1 = (_flex1 * height) / (_flex1 + _flex2 + _flex3);
  var height2 = (_flex2 * height) / (_flex1 + _flex2 + _flex3);
  var height3 = (_flex3 * height) / (_flex1 + _flex2 + _flex3);

  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Flex"),),
    body: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        AnimatedContainer(
          duration: _duration,
          color: Colors.blue,
          height: height1,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text("Flex: ${_flex1}", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        ),
        AnimatedContainer(
          duration: _duration,
          color: Colors.red,
          height: height2,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text("Flex: ${_flex2}", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        ),
        AnimatedContainer(
          duration: _duration,
          color: Colors.teal,
          height: height3,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text("Flex: ${_flex3}", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```